# bluetoothd segfault after resume from sleep

Tags: mouse, suspend, bluetooth

I paired the mouse with usb dongle and trusted the mouse in the bluetoothctl. When resume from a sleep, the connection seems recover successfully telling from the bluetoothctl screen print. However the mouse is not usable. Looking at the paired-devices the mouse is gone. Using pair command in bluetoothctl results in segfault of bluetoothd.

```
USB dongle: CSR 8510
    ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
kernel at 5.0.0-29
bluez                                         5.48-0ubuntu3.1
```

The error in syslog is like this:

```
bluetoothd[1156]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.90 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
bluetoothd[1156]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.90 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
bluetoothd[1156]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
bluetoothd[1156]: message repeated 4 times: [ bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)]
bluetoothd[1156]: Error reading PNP_ID value: Unexpected error code
bluetoothd[1156]: Error reading PNP_ID value: Request attribute has encountered an unlikely error
bluetoothd[1156]: Pair device timed out for hci0
bluetoothd[1156]: Pair device timed out for hci0
bluetoothd[1156]: Pair device timed out for hci0
bluetoothd[1156]: Pair device timed out for hci0
kernel: [29452.939601] bluetoothd[1156]: segfault at 0 ip 000055951130a576 sp 00007ffd80ad8450 error 4 in bluetoothd[5595112a1000+f3000]
systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
```

from time to time, it has another problem:

```
gnome-shell[1646]: Error setting property 'Powered' on interface org.bluez.Adapter1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.226 was not provided by any .service files (g-dbus-error-quark, 2)
gnome-shell[2035]: Error setting property 'Powered' on interface org.bluez.Adapter1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.226 was not provided by any .service files (g-dbus-error-quark, 2)
```

Is this some known bug or there is some configuration I did wrong? If this is a known bug how can work around it?